# Getting a blank screen after installing the PHPMyAadmin in the ubuntu server

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin, aws

I am new to AWS setup. I am trying to install Apache, PHP, and PhpMyAdmin on the server.

I have tried the below steps.

1. Created Instance.

2. Tried the below command to log in to the Instance using terminal

a. `chmod 400 demo1.pem`

b. Yes

c. Next add the command `ssh -i "demo1.pem" ubuntu@ec2-ipaddress.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com`

3. Installed the apache2 on the server using the below command

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apache2 -y
apache2 -version
sudo systemctl status apache2

//Restarted Apache
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

4. Installed PHP using below command

```
sudo apt install php-all-dev
sudo apt install php-intl
sudo apt install php-mbstring
```

5. Installed MySQL server using the below command

   sudo apt install mysql-server

6. Installed the PHPMyAadmin using the below command

```
sudo apt install phpmyadmin
```

While installing the PHPMyAdmin I installed it in the apache server, and set the username and password.

Now when I run the `ipaddress/phpmyadmin` in the URL then I am getting a blank page.

Is there anything steps that are missing in my above steps?

I have MAC Air and using the terminal.

Ubuntu version

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Comment: Any and all questions need to have and will usually benefit from have the version of Ubuntu in the question. Please EDIT and add this info.

Comment: @David, I have updated the ubuntu version in the question. Please check it once.